# AWS EC2 instance randomly rebooting several times a day

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a t2.nano instance that often reboots several times a day, as shown in the `last reboot` log:

```
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-74-generi Tue Sep 12 17:26 - 19:15  (01:49)
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-74-generi Tue Sep 12 13:58 - 19:15  (05:17)
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-74-generi Tue Sep 12 11:13 - 19:15  (08:02)
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-74-generi Tue Sep 12 00:48 - 19:15  (18:27)
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-74-generi Fri Sep  1 23:48 - 19:15 (10+19:27)
```

As you can see, the server was up and running for 10 days, until it randomly reboots. It then reboots a total of 4 times over the next few hours.

There is nothing in `/var/log/syslog` at the time of reboot. Initially the instance is running a web server, but after the first reboot, the web server is not configured to start back up automatically. Therefore, nothing is running on my server, yet the instance still reboots several more times.

What's going on here? Is it likely that I'm being hacked or there's a problem with Amazon's servers?

Comment: I don't believe there's a widespread issue across multiple AWS servers that would be causing your problem; I have several `t2.nano` instances that have been up for hundreds of days without rebooting. Does CloudWatch reveal any suspicious metrics around the times that your instance is rebooting? What application is running on this machine? Is a `t2.nano` instance big enough for your application?

Answer (score 0):

Reboots look to be taking place at `19:15`
Do you have any scripts or cronjobs running that could be playing a part in it?

Comment: My rep isn't enough to comment on question :(

Comment: No, 19:15 is the time that I ran the `last reboot` command. The reboot times are 00:48, 11:13, 13:58, and 17:26.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

https://status.aws.amazon.com/

Reboots should be expected, but no more frequently than you'd expect them with commodity hardware